# Button doesn't show up on android app

Tags: android, eclipse, button, adt

I'm making a simple android app with a button but it doesn't wanna appear and I really don't understand why. This is my code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.pressme_alpha.MainActivity" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/money"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/press_me"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:onClick="handleButtonClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I open the app, the Text works and shows up, but the button just doesn't appear.

Comment: where is your activity's java code?

Comment: Try doing a _Project -> Clean..._ if you're using Eclipse.

Comment: Restart your eclipse or Do clean your project. I can't see anything wrong with that code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running this code and the button does show up. 
However there's no additional text as both of your TextView score and money have text set to blank -==> android:text=""
The button appears with the text "Press me" on it.